# Execute script after `python manage.py shell` is up

Tags: python, django, shell, alias

There is a command that calls Django's shell:

```
python manage.py shell
```

I would like to create a BASH-alias, that will:

1. Start `python manage.py shell`
2. Execute `print 'foo'`

Something similar to -i option: `python -i /usr/bin/print_foo.py` but with `manage.py shell`

The reason for doing it is too speed up the debug process. So instead of importing all relevant models and assigning variables, I want to do it in the separate PY file. So each time I start the `manage.py shell`, I will just have all the tools in hand.

**EDIT**: using `python manage.py shell < /usr/bin/print_foo.py` almost does the trick. However the terminal gets closed.. if there is a way to make it stay opened.

Comment: Can you give some more context, i.e. what are you really trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PYTHONSTARTUP="$1"      # Set the startup script python will run when it start.
shift                          # Remove the first argument, don't want to pass that.
python manage.py shell "$@"    # Run manage.py with the startup script.
```

Just supply the python script you want to run first as the first argument to the script. All other arguments are directly passed to `manage.py`. The change to `$PYTHONSTARTUP` won't affect the environment in your shell.

Comment: Thanks! That is a short and elegant solution.

Comment: When I run this script, it ends with opening the shell and waiting for a command.
Even in background, it keeps running.
Is there a way to close/exit that?

Comment: I think you should be able to do 'exit'

Answer (score 2):

I also battled with this, the `< test.py` closes the shell,  and `shell_plus` doesn't add much here beside auto loading of the models, doesn't load the code you want to debug

However I can do this: I make a `test.py` that is initializes Django if it's not ran from a Django environment, and run it with `python -i test.py`
The basic idea is to not use `manage.py shell`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This will run e.g. from python -i test.py, but will be skipped if from Django
    import django  # 1.7
    import os
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')
    django.setup()

# Your regular Django stuff here


# Init your vars etc and prepare values to debug
# The Python prompt will remain active here so you can work on it
```

Another less automated solution is to call `execfile('test.py')` or `%run test.py` if you're in IPython,
pro is you can reload the `test.py` module without leaving the shell (faster and preserves the context), con is you have to load it manually when the shell opens up

Comment: With ``shell_plus`` you could use the ``SHELL_PLUS_POST_IMPORTS`` and ``SHELL_PLUS_PRE_IMPORTS`` settings to load up code in a module on startup automatically. Not that this is better, but it's possible.

Comment: Yes, problem is it's "global", the same modules are always loaded with the shell_plus, I can't load/run specific modules when I want to debug `orange.py` or `apple.py`, unless I go back and change the settings again

Comment: That's true, if you want it to be as flexible as to having multiple different bootstrap scripts then that's not possible, although you could limit it to one imported module that provides different setup functions like ``foo.setup_orange()`` and ``foo.setup_apple()``. But that way you again have to type one line before you can start, so that's that. :)

Comment: Dear OP, Mark this one as 'Accepted'

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but Django Extensions ([Github](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions), [Docs](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)) [`shell_plus`](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/shell_plus.html) might be interesting for that. (the package has many useful tools, so it is a valuable dependency in many cases.)

The app's models are automatically imported. To configure further imports, see the [additional imports](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/shell_plus.html#additional-imports) section.

If you want to automatically execute code from arbitrary python modules with `shell_plus`, you can use the `SHELL_PLUS_PRE_IMPORTS` and `SHELL_PLUS_POST_IMPORTS` setting. Any python modules that are configured there run a) before or b) after Django's app models are auto-imported.